# How do I access a constructor with user input in C#

Tags: c#

In my program I have multiple instances of a specific class Tracer (A1,B2,C3 etc).  Using a listbox called tracerListBox, the user will determine which tracer they want to use.

Lets say each tracer has a constructor named family.

I know that if I wanted to access the family of, say, A1 I would simply type:

```
    A1.family
```

However, I want to write code that accomplishes something like this:

```
    tracerListBox.Text.family
```

Is there a way to pass a user-determined value to a constructor? I essentially want the user to determine which instance of Class Tracer to use and then use that information to pull all of the information about that specific tracer.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Why not using simple `if(listBox.Text == "A1") { use A1.family }`? Or map it via dictionary would be more generic. If family display text the same as a type you can do this using reflection but I would suggest avoid reflection if possible

Comment: I am trying to avoid a bunch of if statements as the program will ultimately have a vast amount of tracers. I wasn't aware you could make a call like the one you listed above however, so I will definitely keep it in mind. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Constructors don't have names.  It looks like `family` is either a *property* or a *field* (though there are other possibilities).

Comment: @wcard: is so why you've accepted the answer which suggest multiple `if` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the detail to actually make a decision is missing from your question.  However, we can point you in the general directions that may answer your question.

- **Reflection** would definitely help.  Look at `object.GetType()` to start.
- Check out different **Dependency Injection** or **Inversion of Control (IOC)** libraries.  They may be just what you need.

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip.  Half of my problem in learning this language is not having the vocabulary to search for what I need,  especially as I go more in depth.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is a [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), sometimes also called a *virtual constructor* (which is not technically correct, because it's neither a constructor nor a virtual method).

Instead of calling a constructor, you call a static method that calls a constructor of the class determined by the arguments passed in.

```
interface ITracer {
    void Trace(string s);
}
class TracerA : ITracer {
    public void Trace(string s) {
        // ...
    }
}
class TracerB : ITracer {
    public void Trace(string s) {
        // ...
    }
}
class TracerFactory {
    public static ITracer Make(string name) {
        if (name.Equals("A")) return new TracerA();
        if (name.Equals("B")) return new TracerB();
        throw new ApplicationException("Unknown: "+name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
string myType = "MyNamespace." + tracerListBox.Text + ", MyAssembly";
var = Type.GetType( myType );
var property = t.GetProperty("family", BindingFlags.Static);
```